# AlarmManager not accepting time from timepicker

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, timepicker

I am making an application and my alarm manager is firing if i provide a fixed time, but it is not working if i am taking time from a timepicker.

The TimePicker:-

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      final  Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
       int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
       TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
       mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
           @Override
           public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
               //tv.setText( selectedHour + " : " + selectedMinute);  
               mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR,selectedHour);
               mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,selectedMinute);
             l= mcurrentTime.getTimeInMillis();
             tv.setText(String.valueOf(l));
           }
       }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour tim
       mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
       mTimePicker.show();

   }
 });
```

And my alarm manager code:-

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    int randomPIN = (int)(Math.random()*9000)+1000;
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, randomPIN, myIntent,pendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,l , pendingIntent);
```

it is working if i do:

```
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,System.CurrentTimeInMillis()+8000 , pendingIntent);
```

but not if i do:-

```
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,l , pendingIntent);
```

where l comes from timepicker code above.

I think i made my point clear, please reply
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by not accepting? post your logcat

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira oh sorry, not accepting means, not working if i use time from time picker, but works fine if i use a fixed predefined time..

Comment: RTC neans: "Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall clock time in UTC", so pass your time in that format

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira didn't work..  System.currentTimeMillis() alsro returns in UTC.. and working fine..

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 different `Calendar` parts: `HOUR` and `HOUR_OF_DAY`:

```
   int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   ...
   mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR,selectedHour);
```

You might try setting the hour using `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` instead.

NOTE: To check that you are using the correct time, try converting `l` to a human-readable time and logging it.